Kafka broker does not receive message from python producer
Hello i use the following configuration for Kafka using docker compose
compose_kafka.yml
version: '3'

services:
  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      ZOO_MY_ID: 1
  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    container_name: kafka
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: 192.168.1.10
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
  kafka_manager:
    image: kafkamanager/kafka-manager
    container_name: kafka-manager
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    environment:
      ZK_HOSTS: "192.168.1.10:2181"
      APPLICATION_SECRET: "random-secret"

I create a producer which produces messages to the kafka server
Generate.py
from faker import Faker

fake = Faker()

class Registered_user:

    def get_registered_user():
        return {
            "name": fake.name(),
            "address": fake.address(),
            "created_at": fake.year()
        }

Producer_registered_user.py
import time
import json
from kafka import KafkaProducer
from fake_data import Generate

  
def json_serializer(data):
    return json.dumps(data).encode("utf-8")


producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers='192.168.1.10:9092',
                         value_serializer=json_serializer)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    while 1 == 1:
        user = Generate.Registered_user.get_registered_user()
        producer.send('registered_user', user)
        print(user)
        time.sleep(4)


But the consumer does not receive any messages:

Consumer_registered_user.py
import json
from kafka import KafkaConsumer

if __name__ == '__main__':
    consumer = KafkaConsumer(
        bootstrap_servers='192.168.1.10:9092',
        auto_offset_reset="from-beginning",
        group_id="consumer-group-a"
    )

    for message in consumer:
        print("User = {}".format(json.loads(message.value)))

I also checked if the topic is listed under the topics:

and if kafka received the messages:

Could you please help me with this problem?

Ensure your topic is listed - docker exec -it kafka kafka-topics.sh --list --bootstrap-server 192.168.1.10:9092

Thanks for the fast reply! I checked (see edited post) and they exist

Use Kafka Console Consumer to Verify Messages are recieved - docker exec -it kafka kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server 192.168.1.10:9092 --topic registered_user --from-beginning

Thanks Jeevan ebi, for the fast reply! In the adjusted post i see that the messages are showed. But the script (also put in the post) and CMAK didn't show the messages ( or the ammount of messages).  How can i fix that ?

Check your consumer application configuration,
Sample:
from kafka import KafkaConsumer

consumer = KafkaConsumer(
    'topic_1', 'topic_2',
    bootstrap_servers='192.168.1.10:9092',
    auto_offset_reset='earliest',
    enable_auto_commit=True,
    group_id='my-group'
)

#Make sure the consumer is successfully subscribing to all required topics
print(consumer.subscription()) 

for message in consumer:
    print(f"Received from {message.topic}: {message.value.decode('utf-8')}")

Add topic to your consumer:
Consumer_registered_user.py
import json
from kafka import KafkaConsumer

if __name__ == '__main__':
    consumer = KafkaConsumer(
        'registered_user',  # Specify the topic you want to consume
        bootstrap_servers='192.168.1.10:9092',
        auto_offset_reset="earliest",  # Correct value
        group_id="consumer-group-a"
    )

    for message in consumer:
        print("User = {}".format(json.loads(message.value.decode('utf-8'))))

Issues:

Missing Topic Subscription: You need to pass the topic name ('registered_user') as the first argument to KafkaConsumer to ensure your consumer subscribes to that topic.

Setting auto_offset_reset="earliest" ensures that if there are no committed offsets, the consumer will start reading from the earliest available message in the topic.


Ref - https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-clients/python/current/overview.html

Thanks! The consumer works. The CMAK (Kafka manager still doesn't give the right presentation of the messages.

@Erikhoeven - that could be found by debugging your CMAK application.
